# Using Javascript to upload files to AWS s3

Tags: javascript, ruby-on-rails, amazon-web-services, amazon-s3

In my rails app, I'm trying to upload files to AWS s3. I followed the this tutorial,https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/direct-to-s3-image-uploads-in-rails. I'm using the aws-sdk gem and jQuery File Upload Plugin to upload files. In my app i have a resource with two attributes: name, and file, and the file is a string. When the file is uploaded to the S3 bucket the URL is suppose to be saved into my database.

But when I tried to upload a file in my application it saved this to my database: **#\u003cActionDispatch::Http::UploadedFile:0x007fa212ad40b0\u003e**, instead of saving the link to the file from where its stored in AWS S3.

This is the code in my controller pertaining to the file uploaded.:

```
def new
   @s3_direct_post = S3_BUCKET.presigned_post(key: "uploads/#{SecureRandom.uuid}/${filename}", success_action_status: 201, acl: :public_read)
   @resource = @person.resources.build
end
```

And the code in my form for the file upload is just a simple view with a file upload field.

The code of the javascript I'm using to upload the file is:

```
$(function() { $('.directUpload').find("input:file").each(function(i, elem) 

{
    var fileInput    = $(elem);
    var form         = $(fileInput.parents('form:first'));
    var submitButton = form.find('input[type="submit"]');
    var progressBar  = $("<div class='bar'></div>");
    var barContainer = $("<div class='progress'></div>").append(progressBar);
    fileInput.after(barContainer);
    fileInput.fileupload({
      fileInput:       fileInput,
      url:             '<%= @s3_direct_post.url %>',
      type:            'POST',
      autoUpload:       true,
      formData:         <%= @s3_direct_post.fields.to_json.html_safe %>,
      paramName:        'file', // S3 does not like nested name fields i.e. name="user[avatar_url]"
      dataType:         'XML',  // S3 returns XML if success_action_status is set to 201
      replaceFileInput: false,
      progressall: function (e, data) {
        var progress = parseInt(data.loaded / data.total * 100, 10);
        progressBar.css('width', progress + '%')
      },
      start: function (e) {
        submitButton.prop('disabled', true);

        progressBar.
          css('background', 'green').
          css('display', 'block').
          css('width', '0%').
          text("Loading...");
      },
      done: function(e, data) {
        submitButton.prop('disabled', false);
        progressBar.text("Uploading done");

        // extract key and generate URL from response
        var key   = $(data.jqXHR.responseXML).find("Key").text();
        var url   = '//<%= @s3_direct_post.url.host %>/' + key;

        // create hidden field
        var input = $("<input />", { type:'hidden', name: fileInput.attr('name'), value: url })
        form.append(input);
      },
      fail: function(e, data) {
        submitButton.prop('disabled', false);

        progressBar.
          css("background", "red").
          text("Failed"); }});});});
```

If you could help me out that would be great! And if there is any other code that you need to look at just ask.

Comment: Why not use [EvaporateJS](https://github.com/TTLabs/EvaporateJS). Its is the fastest and best way to upload files directly from the data source location. No intermediate server required.